# Numpy Vectorise - Using default value where not defined

Tags: arrays, numpy, vectorization, default

I have a function as below

```
def myfunc(a, b=4):
    "Return a-b if a>b, otherwise return a+b"
    if a > b:
        return a - b
    else:
        return a + b
```

In above function default value for `b` is defined. I need to apply this function on a list where in some cases I want to use the default value.

Vectorised using following code:

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)
```

For 2nd and 4th value of `a` i.e. `2` and `4` I want to use the default value of `b` i.e. 4 to make the calculation

I've tried using below code but wouldn't work

```
res = vfunc([1, 2, 3, 4],[1,None,2, None])
```

How can I pass array such that for 2nd and 4th value of `a` the default value of `b` is used?

Comment: You can't. `vectorize` will pass `None` to your function.  It doesn't compile or look at the function's internals.

Comment: What I understand is passing default values can't be achieved with `np. vectorize`. Is there another way to pass list of args along with default using another method instead of `np. vectorize`?

Comment: You need another function layer, one that calls `myfunc(a, b)` or `myfunc(a)` depending on whether `b` is `None` or not.  This list comprehension might be easier to understand `[func(a,b) for a,b in zip([1, 2, 3, 4],[1,None,2, None])]`.